# Detect UINavigationController anmation complete when subView covers the current view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view being shown in a `navigation controller`. I have added a `subview` to the navigation controller's view so that it covers up all of the view that is being shown except for the `navigation bar` itself. The subView has been added like - 
'`[self.navigationController addSubView:mySubView];`'

On some action on the `subView`, I want to to do the following in sequence-

1. Pop the current `view controller` on the navigation stack with animation and then.
2. After the view controller is popped and the animation is complete, remove the `subview` from the navigation controller view

The reason why I need to do this is that I need to show the animation of the navigation bar title before removing the sub view.

So I would like to get the event of navigation controller animation completed and then remove the subView.

`viewDidAppear`, `viewWillAppear` or `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` do not help, as the subView covers the underlying view on the navigation stack and these methods never get called.

Currently I am just removing the subview after a delay hoping that the animation has completed. But I know that this is not a reliable way to do what I want.

Is there any other way that I can accomplish the sequence of events that I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass the navigation controller, and implement the delegate method, navigationBar:didPopItem:, which is called after the navigation bar animation is completed. You can remove your subview in that method.